How does tensorflow handle nested lists in model output when computing losses?
I'm trying to write an implementation of the pix2pixhd model (using tensorflow v2.10.0), which utilises a discriminator model D, comprising 3 sub-models D1, D2, D3. These operate at various resolutions, and each Dn returns the discriminator output (is the image real/fake) as well as a set of intermediate features, for use in the authors' "improved adversarial loss".
My combined discriminator model D calls each Dn, and concatenates the outputs and features to separate lists, such that the output of the D model looks like:
D.output = [output, features]

where:
output = [D1_output, D2_output, D3_output]
features = [[D1_feat_1, D1_feat_2, ...],
            [D2_feat_1, D2_feat_2, ...],
            [D3_feat_1, D3_feat_2, ...]]

The model compiles fine and produces the expected output data/structures, however I can't understand how these structures are handled when it comes to computing the loss during training.
Initially I had assumed that I could set:
D.compile(loss=[output_loss_fn, features_loss_fn])

and pass "y_true" data with identical structure to the model outputs. However, it seems that tensorflow does not pass the entire nested list and instead passes one element at a time:

output_loss_fn operates on D1_output
features_loss_fn operates on D2_output
warning message: WARNING:tensorflow:Gradients do not exist for variables ['D3_ .....]

so D3 doesn't even seem to be connected in the graph.
I've also tried creating an identical nested structure of loss functions:
D.compile(loss=[[output_loss_fn, output_loss_fn, output_loss_fn],
                [[features_loss_fn, features_loss_fn, ...],
                 [features_loss_fn, features_loss_fn, ...],
                 [features_loss_fn, features_loss_fn, ...]]]

However this gives me exactly the same output as before.
In a nutshell, is there a way to handle these kind of nested outputs, or does the model need restructuring?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read tag descriptions before using them. From [tag:tensorflow]: "Use this tag with a language-specific tag ([python], [c++], [javascript], [r], etc.)(...)". [Edit] your post to add the language you are programming in.

It helps if you share which version of TF or Keras are you using it, as the versions could have different functions, model, arguments, etc.
Not sure if the functions available to tf.keras.Model currently are able to do that. But, you can for sure do this with a custom training loop where you compute the loss with all intermediate features, i.e., connecting the variables in the model for backprop. Link https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough

Hi @K.Bogdan, thanks for the tip - I was able to implement backprop looping over the nested structures in a custom training loop under a tf.GradientTape().
If you wanted to suggest the same as an Answer to my post I would be happy to mark it as accepted.
